# How to keep text within a RichTextBox after my function has ran

Tags: vb.net, textbox, richtextbox

I have been trying to figure out the past several days why my RichTextBox control clears after my program finishes. I have tried changing the true false settings like `Hide Selection`, `Multiline` and others, but nothing works. I even tried switch from a RTB to normal text box and got the same result. At the end, the box is full of writing...and if I click ANYWHERE on my form, the text disappears, it is really annoying.

Main method (snippet):

```
Private Sub Test_Activated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
                If Code = 0 And Check = 1 Then ' Check request is successful
                    program.Read("Velocity_value" Velocity)
                    If Velocity <= 12 Or Velocity > 14 Then
                        MsgBox(ConstString207, vbExclamation, "Velocity")
                    End If

                    Thread.Sleep(2000) ' delay 2 seconds
                    Me.TDisplay.Text = Me.TDisplay.Text & vbCrLf & ConstString125
                    Me.Invalidate()
                    'following steps will read the Code
                    program.Read("Code")
                    Me.TDisplay.Text = Me.TDisplay.Text & vbCrLf & ConstString8 & "" & Code
                    Code = 0
                    Me.Invalidate()
                    labPg1.Increment(12.5)
                    Application.DoEvents()
                    ' calling safety check  function to check valocity is safe to operate
                    SafetyCheck()
End Sub
```

RichTextBox:

```
Private Sub TDisplay_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'set the current caret position to the end
        TDisplay.SelectionStart = TDisplay.Text.Length
        'scroll it automatically
        TDisplay.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your first problem is that you have no `End If` for your first `If`

Comment: What is Thread.Sleep and the Invalidate and the (argh!) DoEvents supposed to be doing? Why are they necessary.

Comment: @Mary main method is a snippet, I have 600 more lines of code after that. There is an ```End If ```.  The program runs correctly, just when I click after it finishes, the text disappears.

Comment: @Mary the threading.sleep is waiting to see what my program "reads" on the speed of velocity, it is communicating with another device via usb. The Invalidate just refreshes because I am reading a lot of values. The DoEvents returns the values that are changing. I know this might be bad practice, but wasn't sure how else to do this.

Comment: @Mary LOL, that person is me...sadly. I am working on optimizing it. However, do you have a guess to why the text disappears?

Comment: Some tips: 1) Replace all `Me.TDisplay.Text = Me.TDisplay.Text & vbCrLf & ConstStringXXX` lines with `Me.TDisplay.AppendText($"{vbCrLf} {ConstStringXXX}")`. Better to create a method for that. 2) Set the `TDisplay.HideSelection = True`. 3) In `If` statements, use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead of `And` and `Or`. 4) You shouldn't freeze the main thread by calling `Thread.Sleep(2000)`, use `async` calls instead.